# Big gap within a cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this. Both cells contain another table. The problem is the space below the inner `table`.

[image]

This is the code:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td align=center valign=middle>
      <div style="float: left">
        X
      </div>
      <table border=1>
        <tr height="33%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 7px">
            4x1.00
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="66%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 10px">
            <b>4</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center valign=middle>
      <div style="float: left">
        2
      </div>
      <table border=1>
        <tr height="33%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 7px">
            4x1.50
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="66%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 10px">
            <b>6</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And it works in jsfiddle, but not on my page. Theoretically there is no other css setting applied for it. http://jsfiddle.net/fishmong3r/f1ktbyeh/1/

Comment: did you tried using Normazlie.css ?

Comment: @PeterWilson Haven't even heard about it so far. But I've just tried it now. No luck.

Comment: try to use the developer tool on the browser to inspect the underlying issue!

Comment: What browser you use? @fishmong3r

Comment: @fishmong3r then right-click on one of the cells that has the issue and choose "Inspect" from the menu. or hit F12 to inspect the element. You may be able to identify if there is a css rule that affects your cells

Comment: @fishmong3r Normalize.css is just normalize all CSS properties to let all browsers acting the same behavior . as example `body` have `margin:8px;` on chrome .. Normalize reset it to `margin:0px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a general setting and this suit your problem then you can specify in your `css` the following:

```
table td{
  padding:0px;
}
```

For cross-browser compatibility issue, you may want to try this:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: I tried on the first place. No luck, even with the infamous `!important` tag.

Comment: No, it's still not OK.

Comment: OK, I'm a moron. Never mind. It's OK now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its due to CSS only.
I guess you should check your code again. There might be possibilities where your css getting loaded from main page[Layout html] and you don't now. Check your code using [View Source].

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="68" height="88" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td width="58" height="40" align=right valign=top>
      <div style="float: left">
        X
      </div>
      <table border=1>
        <tr height="33%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 7px">
            4x1.00
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="66%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 10px">
            <b>4</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40" align=right valign=top>
      <div style="float: left">
        2
      </div>
      <table border=1>
        <tr height="33%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 7px">
            4x1.50
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="66%">
          <td align=center style="font-size: 10px">
            <b>6</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```